# extract 2D slice (defined by aribtrary plane) from 3D volume again?

Tags: ndimage, simpleitk

extract 2D slice (defined by arbitrary plane intersection)  from 3D volume using either iTK or scipy ndimage and interpolation with SimpleITK.
Does anyone have a working example ? I have read several posts here and on the ITK users list but no one has a something that works. 
Thanks

GT

Comment: How are you defining your plane? How are your defining your image domain?

Comment: the image is read with simpleitk like so: itkimage = sitk.ReadImage(mhd_file) , for the bounds one can get easily 0*itkimage.GetSpacing()[0] + itkimage.GetOrigin()[0], (itkimage.GetWidth()-1)*itkimage.GetSpacing()[0]  + itkimage.GetOrigin()[0], for the plane, I am using a normal [n1,n2,n3] and two vectors, u, and v which orthogonal to the normal. thanks

Comment: So you have a good orthonormal basis. Are these vector is the physical space domain or the pixel space domain? or Some other? It would be easiest if is was Physical space. With this information you system is still under determined, you also need a point which the plane is passing through.

Comment: These are all defined in physical space and I have one point on the plane. Do you have a pseudocode or snippet ? Thanks //GT